# Freeing malloc 2D matrix

Tags: c, windows

My program isn't deleting the arrays, always stops at the freeing point. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int** t;
    t=(int**)malloc(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        t[i]=(int*)malloc(m);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            t[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        free (t[0]);
    }
    free (t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shoudnt this `free (t[0]);` by `free (t[i]);`.. and dont cast the return of `malloc()`

Comment: Do you know that `malloc(n)` allcos `n` **bytes**, not `n` **`int`s**?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to free the first element several times, instead free each only once,
 including the first ( i = 0 ) element.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    free (t[i]);
```

You also don't allocate enough space with malloc:

```
t = malloc( n * sizeof(int*) ) ;
```

and

```
t[i] = malloc( m * sizeof(int) ) ;
```

Also check the return value of your scanf call since it might fail, and check for values of n and m to be withing required ranges.

Comment: `*int` --> `*t` or `int*`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That was an typo, you could have edited that you know.

Comment: Possibility of your intentions as already commented there was multiple.  it seems that it would be arrogant to make such modifications.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY All right. Next time you don't have to be shy and just edit. :-) If someone won't like the edit, it can always be reverted.